# Are there any cases when React updates DOM automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

All articles I've read on React show the code when I should explicitly call `this.setState()` to trigger DOM update. This seems to be **manual** triggering of change detection. I call `this.setState`, React re-renders Virtual DOM and then compares it with the native DOM for changes - if anything changed, the DOM is updated. [Here is the quote](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) from the docs:

> 4) Every second the browser calls the tick() method. Inside it, the
>   Clock component schedules a UI update by calling setState() with an
>   object containing the current time. **Thanks to the setState() call,
>   React knows the state has changed**, and calls render() method again
>   to learn what should be on the screen.

Compare it with Angular digest cycle which **automatically** checks for binding changes and updates DOM. Although I have a way to trigger manual changed detection for a component, it's usually not needed.

My question is whether there are any cases when React triggers DOM update without requiring me to call `this.setState()` manually, i.e. automatic virtual DOM update?

Comment: react components are rendering either by internally setting state or by externally changing their Props there is no other way.

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon, thanks, can you please provide some examples? I'm particularly interested in cases when properties are changed and I don't need to call `setState`, but the DOM will still be updated

Comment: if you are looking into equating your angular experience with react i would say you are missing a few pieces of the puzzle. you can look into `redux` for data flow management. there is no clean way for you to just using react to change component's props w/o altering some components state.  in order to achieve this you will need something like redux to keep your state external kinda like a data service in react from which you can draw data and inject it into the components as properties. you will need to be familiar with flux and if you intent to build an application you you'll have to anyways.

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon, no, I'm not going to a build react app. I've worked with Flux and Redux before and know what they do. But they are not what I'm asking about here. I'm looking at the change detection mechanism, i.e. figuring out that component's properties changed, not state management. Right now, it seems that I should explicitly tell React that this happened, it can't understand it by itself. The only time it understands is when parent component updates  child component properties, but even in this case it seems that only a lifecycle hook is triggered but I still need to call `setState`

Comment: no, when a parent component updates a child and the properties change the child component will be re-rendered. what data is presented is entirely up to how the render method is implemented, if you follow the lifecycle methods you'll see that when properties are changed 5 methods are fired https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#updating each one of them with a specific purpose and arguments. there is no autmatic change detection in react, that would require using observers and bidirectional data flow. that is not how react was designed.

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon, _there is no autmatic change detection in react, that would require using observers and bidirectional data flow. that is not how react was designed._ - thanks, that what I was looking for. Many articles I've read claim that virtual DOM is how change detection is implemented, but I don't see it this way. For the Virtual DOM to be updated, first the framework should detect component state changes. Thanks for your comments, maybe put them as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is a state machine that maintains a virtual representation of the DOM in memory, which *automatically* updates/renders (where appropriate) when this state changes.

The reason you see `setState` being called to *trigger* a rerender is because this is the most common (only?) means of updating the data structure that feeds this internal DOM representation (which will in turn feed down through the properties of children).

It's not that `setState` is a manual call to rerender, it's that `setState` causes the state to *change,* which in turn causes React to run a diff and update where appropriate.  It's all about cascading the data to reflect the *current* state of your application.  If that state hasn't changed then there's nothing to update, and therefore no need to rerender.

This is also why it's a very bad idea to mutate the DOM out from under React, as this more often than not results in a loss of parity between React's virtual representation of the DOM and the *actual* DOM.

Try not to think about React data bindings in terms of Angular bindings, rather think about it in terms of emulating what Angular bindings do within the context of step-by-step state changes.

Comment: thanks, _which **automatically** updates/renders (where appropriate) when this state changes._ - but only if the state is changed through `setState` correct?

Comment: It triggers the lifecycle methods, yeah.  You can conditionally block these using methods like `shouldComponentUpdate`, but by default if props change on a component then you're gonna get a rerender

Comment: _by default **if props change** on a component then you're gonna get a rerender_ - **this** is possible only if parent component state changes, correct? and when parent component state changes, it re-renders parent and **all its children**, updating props on these children and calling [lifecycle hooks](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#updating)?

Comment: Not all children will update.  React has some smarts built in (such as `PureComponent`) that allow you to limit rerenders to only children that are actually receiving updated values for their props.  But yes, state has to change to get anything to rerender, and the way to do that is to call `setState` from somewhere